# Diffrence between floor and ceil when using dates

Tags: php, mysql, excel, date

when using ceil and i enter 2013-02-28 as the start and 2013-05-30 as the end, i get 92 days between the two:

```
return ceil(($end - $start) / $medium);
```

while with floor i get 91 days:

```
return floor(($end - $start) / $medium);
```

When i do this in excel, and mysql using the datediff function, i also get 91, what is the difference between the rwo and which one is the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

ceil — Round fractions up
floor — Round fractions down

> ceil (4.1) = 5
>       floor (4.1) = 4

Answer (score 0):

`ceil()` function used to get the next highest integer value by rounding fractions up whereas `floor()` function converts a specified numeric value to the next lowest integer value by rounding.

So when you are using ceil(), the value you get and if it contains decimal points it will always be rounded to the next highest integer but floor will round it to the next lowest integer.

More info on ceil and floor can be found here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

But I think just use floor to get the correct output :

```
$end = "2013-02-28";
$start = "2013-05-30";
$medium = '60*60*24';

$difference = abs(strtotime($end) - strtotime($start));
$days = floor(($difference)/ ($medium));

echo $days ;
```

Hope this helps you :)